# Windows Batch File: How to run multiple batch commands?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm trying to do some basic functionality using a batch file but the batch file opens cmd and runs the first command but then stops, ignoring the other commands. I've tried using `START` and `CALL` but neither I have had any success with, can anyone provide advice?

Batch file looks as below:

```
CD C:\Random\Madeup\Path
cmd.exe /K "npm install" 
CALL gulp-publish.BAT
CD C:\Random\Madeup\Path\mobile\dist
REN C:\Random\Madeup\Path\mobile\dist\config.xml config-publish.txt
PAUSE
```

Comment: Why are you executing `npm` via a separate `cmd` instance?

Comment: I'm thinking since you open a new `cmd` instance, the other commands past that don't run as they try to install packages on the first `cmd` instance. 
Since `gulp` needs `npm`, it will return an error as for the first `cmd` instance `npm` is not installed. The commands on the first `cmd` instance still continue even if `npm install` was not finished installing on the second `cmd` instance. 

That's whats causing the issue in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The batch file opens cmd and runs the first command but then stops

```
cmd.exe /K "npm install"
```

That is what `/k` is intended to do:

```
/K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
       This is useful for testing, to examine variables
```

It runs `cmd` and then immediately returns to the enclosing `cmd` shell, which aslo bypasses the rest of the commands in the batch file.

Try replacing that line with:

```
npm install
```

or:

```
call npm install
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.